# Packet Sniffer found, what next?

Tags: security, rootkit

After a download yesterday my computer crashed.
I updated today and checked for rootkits. I found a packet sniffer

```
eth0: PACKET SNIFFER(/sbin/dhclient[3966])
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: How did you check for rootkits?

Comment: sudo chkrootkit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be a false positive.  Try checking with **rkhunter**, because it gives fewer false positives.  To download  **rkhunter**, and for more detailed info on how to use it, [See this site](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/)

If it come up clean, then you have reason for concern.

Try this as well:

1. `rkhunter --check`
2. `update`
3. `sudo rkhunter --propupd`
4. `rkhunter --check`

<sup>Source: [The Rootkit Hunter project](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

Comment: Checked with the rkhunter -c command and had one warning:         /usr/bin/unhide.rb            [ Warning ]

Comment: Checking for passwd file changes     [ Warning ]
Checking for group file changes       [ Warning ]
Checking for hidden files and directories [ Warning ]

Comment: Mitch: Did all things listed above. Found one file that is replaced by a script and is not whitelisted                                                  Warning: The command '/usr/bin/unhide.rb' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/unhide.rb: Ruby script, ASCII                                                              Should I worry? Thanks for all you time, Wes

Comment: rkhunter is informing you the unhide.rb executable located in /usr/bin/ is a ruby script. It is perfectly normal in that case
and you can white-list it in rkhunter.conf

Comment: Well, the unide thing is different. - http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=607224

Comment: This is not a false positive; if you download a fresh bin of dhclient and replace the bin with the new one from `apt-get download isc-dhcp-client` you the error goes away see my answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/258658/eth0-packet-sniffer-sbin-dhclient

Answer (score 3):

The `isc-dhcp-client` and `isc-dhcp-server` packages (DHCP client and server) re-runs their daemons regularly and cause a "packet sniffer" false positive.  The `chkrootkit` package's `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit` script has a workaround for this which tries to replaces the PID with a static string.

However, the workaround for the false positive doesn't work.  This is because on Debian, the binaries from these packages used to end with a version number, e.g. `/sbin/dhclient3`.  But the `chkrootkit` package maintainers never updated `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit` to work with version 4 series of the `isc-dhcp-client` and `isc-dhcp-server` packages, whose files don't have the version number.

To fix this issue, make a backup copy of `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit` then edit it and change...

```
sed -r -e 's,eth(0|1)(:[0-9])?: PACKET SNIFFER\((/sbin/dhclient3|/usr/sbin/dhcpd3)\[[0-9]+\]\),eth\[0|1\]: PACKET SNIFFER\([dhclient3|dhcpd3]{PID}\),' \
```

...to...

```
sed -r -e 's,eth(0|1)(:[0-9])?: PACKET SNIFFER\((/sbin/dhclient|/usr/sbin/dhcpd)\[[0-9]+\]\),eth\[0|1\]: PACKET SNIFFER\([dhclient|dhcpd]{PID}\),' \
```

Be careful to leave the backslash at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

[Dhclient](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/dhclient.8.html) is the standard " Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol Client" for Ubuntu that is needed for when you have not a fixed IP but still want to be reachable from the Internet.

In case you are worried you should check your [dhclient.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/dhclient.conf.5.html) for unwanted entries.

Comment: Checked the dhclient.conf file. Nothing is added.

Comment: @Wes use `apt-get download isc-dhcp-client` to download a fresh deb, extract the package and replace your existing /sbin/dhclient with the newly downloaded one and it should fix the issue. see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/258658/eth0-packet-sniffer-sbin-dhclient