# eth0: PACKET SNIFFER(/sbin/dhclient

Tags: security, dhclient, rootkit, rkhunter

Im new to Ubuntu and would like help please, I ran ProShield and got this error -

```
eth0: PACKET SNIFFER(/sbin/dhclient
```

I ran the following programs below and nothing came up as far as I can see. PLEASE would someone take a look and tell me if anything suspicious is up?

Many Thanks

After that a ran `sudo chkrootkit` and got the following:

```
ROOTDIR is `/'
Checking `amd'...                                           not found
Checking `basename'...                                      not infected
Checking `biff'...                                          not found
Checking `chfn'...                                          not infected
Checking `chsh'...                                          not infected
Checking `cron'...                                          not infected
Checking `crontab'...                                       not infected
Checking `date'...                                          not infected
Checking `du'...                                            not infected
Checking `dirname'...                                       not infected
Checking `echo'...                                          not infected
Checking `egrep'...                                         not infected
Checking `env'...                                           not infected
Checking `find'...                                          not infected
Checking `fingerd'...                                       not found
Checking `gpm'...                                           not found
Checking `grep'...                                          not infected
Checking `hdparm'...                                        not infected
Checking `su'...                                            not infected
Checking `ifconfig'...                                      not infected
Checking `inetd'...                                         not infected
Checking `inetdconf'...                                     not infected
Checking `identd'...                                        not found
Checking `init'...                                          not infected
Checking `killall'...                                       not infected
Checking `ldsopreload'...                                   not infected
Checking `login'...                                         not infected
Checking `ls'...                                            not infected
Checking `lsof'...                                          not infected
Checking `mail'...                                          not found
Checking `mingetty'...                                      not found
Checking `netstat'...                                       not infected
Checking `named'...                                         not found
Checking `passwd'...                                        not infected
Checking `pidof'...                                         not infected
Checking `pop2'...                                          not found
Checking `pop3'...                                          not found
Checking `ps'...                                            not infected
Checking `pstree'...                                        not infected
Checking `rpcinfo'...                                       not found
Checking `rlogind'...                                       not found
Checking `rshd'...                                          not found
Checking `slogin'...                                        not infected
Checking `sendmail'...                                      not infected
Checking `sshd'...                                          not infected
Checking `syslogd'...                                       not tested
Checking `tar'...                                           not infected
Checking `tcpd'...                                          not infected
Checking `tcpdump'...                                       not infected
Checking `top'...                                           not infected
Checking `telnetd'...                                       not found
Checking `timed'...                                         not found
Checking `traceroute'...                                    not infected
Checking `vdir'...                                          not infected
Checking `w'...                                             not infected
Checking `write'...                                         not infected
Checking `aliens'...                                        no suspect files
Searching for sniffer's logs, it may take a while...        nothing found
Searching for rootkit HiDrootkit's default files...         nothing found
Searching for rootkit t0rn's default files...               nothing found
Searching for t0rn's v8 defaults...                         nothing found
Searching for rootkit Lion's default files...               nothing found
Searching for rootkit RSHA's default files...               nothing found
Searching for rootkit RH-Sharpe's default files...          nothing found
Searching for Ambient's rootkit (ark) default files and dirs... nothing found
Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... The following suspicious files and directories were found:  
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386.jinfo /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit

Searching for LPD Worm files and dirs...                    nothing found
Searching for Ramen Worm files and dirs...                  nothing found
Searching for Maniac files and dirs...                      nothing found
Searching for RK17 files and dirs...                        nothing found
Searching for Ducoci rootkit...                             nothing found
Searching for Adore Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for ShitC Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for Omega Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for Sadmind/IIS Worm...                           nothing found
Searching for MonKit...                                     nothing found
Searching for Showtee...                                    nothing found
Searching for OpticKit...                                   nothing found
Searching for T.R.K...                                      nothing found
Searching for Mithra...                                     nothing found
Searching for LOC rootkit...                                nothing found
Searching for Romanian rootkit...                           nothing found
Searching for Suckit rootkit...                             nothing found
Searching for Volc rootkit...                               nothing found
Searching for Gold2 rootkit...                              nothing found
Searching for TC2 Worm default files and dirs...            nothing found
Searching for Anonoying rootkit default files and dirs...   nothing found
Searching for ZK rootkit default files and dirs...          nothing found
Searching for ShKit rootkit default files and dirs...       nothing found
Searching for AjaKit rootkit default files and dirs...      nothing found
Searching for zaRwT rootkit default files and dirs...       nothing found
Searching for Madalin rootkit default files...              nothing found
Searching for Fu rootkit default files...                   nothing found
Searching for ESRK rootkit default files...                 nothing found
Searching for rootedoor...                                  nothing found
Searching for ENYELKM rootkit default files...              nothing found
Searching for common ssh-scanners default files...          nothing found
Searching for suspect PHP files...                          nothing found
Searching for anomalies in shell history files...           Warning: `//home/*****/.pry_history' file size is zero
Checking `asp'...                                           not infected
Checking `bindshell'...                                     not infected
Checking `lkm'...                                           chkproc: nothing detected
chkdirs: nothing detected
Checking `rexedcs'...                                       not found
Checking `sniffer'...                                       lo: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
eth0: PACKET SNIFFER(/sbin/dhclient[11231])
Checking `w55808'...                                        not infected
Checking `wted'...                                          chkwtmp: nothing deleted
Checking `scalper'...                                       not infected
Checking `slapper'...                                       not infected
Checking `z2'...                                            user ****** deleted or never logged from lastlog!
user root deleted or never logged from lastlog!
Checking `chkutmp'...                                       chkutmp: nothing deleted
Checking `OSX_RSPLUG'...                                    not infected
******@Gigabyte-Q1532N ~ $
```

and also

`sudo rkhunter --check`

```
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.0 ]

Checking system commands...

  Performing 'strings' command checks
    Checking 'strings' command                               [ OK ]

  Performing 'shared libraries' checks
    Checking for preloading variables                        [ None found ]
    Checking for preloaded libraries                         [ None found ]
    Checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable                        [ Not found ]

  Performing file properties checks
    Checking for prerequisites                               [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/adduser                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/chroot                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/cron                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/groupadd                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/groupdel                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/groupmod                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/grpck                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/inetd                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/nologin                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/pwck                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/rsyslogd                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/tcpd                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/useradd                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/userdel                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/usermod                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/sbin/vipw                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/awk                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/basename                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/chattr                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/curl                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/cut                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/diff                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/dirname                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/dpkg                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/dpkg-query                                      [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/du                                              [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/env                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/file                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/find                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/GET                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/groups                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/head                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/id                                              [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/killall                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/last                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/lastlog                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/ldd                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/less                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/locate                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/logger                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/lsattr                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/lsof                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/md5sum                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/mlocate                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/newgrp                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/passwd                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/perl                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/pgrep                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/pkill                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/pstree                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/rkhunter                                        [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/rpm                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/runcon                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sha1sum                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sha224sum                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sha256sum                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sha384sum                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sha512sum                                       [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/size                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sort                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/stat                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/strace                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/strings                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/sudo                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/tail                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/test                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/top                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/touch                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/tr                                              [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/uniq                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/users                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/vmstat                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/w                                               [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/watch                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/wc                                              [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/wget                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/whatis                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/whereis                                         [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/which                                           [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/who                                             [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/whoami                                          [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/unhide.rb                                       [ Warning ]
    /usr/bin/gawk                                            [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/lwp-request                                     [ OK ]
    /usr/bin/w.procps                                        [ OK ]
    /sbin/depmod                                             [ OK ]
    /sbin/fsck                                               [ OK ]
    /sbin/ifconfig                                           [ OK ]
    /sbin/ifdown                                             [ OK ]
    /sbin/ifup                                               [ OK ]
    /sbin/init                                               [ OK ]
    /sbin/insmod                                             [ OK ]
    /sbin/ip                                                 [ OK ]
    /sbin/lsmod                                              [ OK ]
    /sbin/modinfo                                            [ OK ]
    /sbin/modprobe                                           [ OK ]
    /sbin/rmmod                                              [ OK ]
    /sbin/route                                              [ OK ]
    /sbin/runlevel                                           [ OK ]
    /sbin/sulogin                                            [ OK ]
    /sbin/sysctl                                             [ OK ]
    /bin/bash                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/cat                                                 [ OK ]
    /bin/chmod                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/chown                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/cp                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/date                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/df                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/dmesg                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/echo                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/ed                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/egrep                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/fgrep                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/fuser                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/grep                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/ip                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/kill                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/less                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/login                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/ls                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/lsmod                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/mktemp                                              [ OK ]
    /bin/more                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/mount                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/mv                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/netstat                                             [ OK ]
    /bin/ping                                                [ OK ]
    /bin/ps                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/pwd                                                 [ OK ]
    /bin/readlink                                            [ OK ]
    /bin/sed                                                 [ OK ]
    /bin/sh                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/su                                                  [ OK ]
    /bin/touch                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/uname                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/which                                               [ OK ]
    /bin/dash                                                [ OK ]

[Press <ENTER> to continue]


Checking for rootkits...

  Performing check of known rootkit files and directories
    55808 Trojan - Variant A                                 [ Not found ]
    ADM Worm                                                 [ Not found ]
    AjaKit Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Adore Rootkit                                            [ Not found ]
    aPa Kit                                                  [ Not found ]
    Apache Worm                                              [ Not found ]
    Ambient (ark) Rootkit                                    [ Not found ]
    Balaur Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    BeastKit Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    beX2 Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    BOBKit Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    cb Rootkit                                               [ Not found ]
    CiNIK Worm (Slapper.B variant)                           [ Not found ]
    Danny-Boy's Abuse Kit                                    [ Not found ]
    Devil RootKit                                            [ Not found ]
    Dica-Kit Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    Dreams Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Duarawkz Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    Enye LKM                                                 [ Not found ]
    Flea Linux Rootkit                                       [ Not found ]
    Fu Rootkit                                               [ Not found ]
    Fuck`it Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    GasKit Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Heroin LKM                                               [ Not found ]
    HjC Kit                                                  [ Not found ]
    ignoKit Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    IntoXonia-NG Rootkit                                     [ Not found ]
    Irix Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    Jynx Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    KBeast Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Kitko Rootkit                                            [ Not found ]
    Knark Rootkit                                            [ Not found ]
    ld-linuxv.so Rootkit                                     [ Not found ]
    Li0n Worm                                                [ Not found ]
    Lockit / LJK2 Rootkit                                    [ Not found ]
    Mood-NT Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    MRK Rootkit                                              [ Not found ]
    Ni0 Rootkit                                              [ Not found ]
    Ohhara Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Optic Kit (Tux) Worm                                     [ Not found ]
    Oz Rootkit                                               [ Not found ]
    Phalanx Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    Phalanx2 Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    Phalanx2 Rootkit (extended tests)                        [ Not found ]
    Portacelo Rootkit                                        [ Not found ]
    R3dstorm Toolkit                                         [ Not found ]
    RH-Sharpe's Rootkit                                      [ Not found ]
    RSHA's Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Scalper Worm                                             [ Not found ]
    Sebek LKM                                                [ Not found ]
    Shutdown Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    SHV4 Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    SHV5 Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    Sin Rootkit                                              [ Not found ]
    Slapper Worm                                             [ Not found ]
    Sneakin Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    'Spanish' Rootkit                                        [ Not found ]
    Suckit Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Superkit Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    TBD (Telnet BackDoor)                                    [ Not found ]
    TeLeKiT Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    T0rn Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    trNkit Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    Trojanit Kit                                             [ Not found ]
    Tuxtendo Rootkit                                         [ Not found ]
    URK Rootkit                                              [ Not found ]
    Vampire Rootkit                                          [ Not found ]
    VcKit Rootkit                                            [ Not found ]
    Volc Rootkit                                             [ Not found ]
    Xzibit Rootkit                                           [ Not found ]
    zaRwT.KiT Rootkit                                        [ Not found ]
    ZK Rootkit                                               [ Not found ]

[Press <ENTER> to continue]


  Performing additional rootkit checks
    Suckit Rookit additional checks                          [ OK ]
    Checking for possible rootkit files and directories      [ None found ]
    Checking for possible rootkit strings                    [ None found ]

  Performing malware checks
    Checking running processes for suspicious files          [ None found ]
    Checking for login backdoors                             [ None found ]
    Checking for suspicious directories                      [ None found ]
    Checking for sniffer log files                           [ None found ]
  Performing trojan specific checks
    Checking for enabled inetd services                      [ Warning ]

  Performing Linux specific checks
    Checking loaded kernel modules                           [ OK ]
    Checking kernel module names                             [ OK ]

[Press <ENTER> to continue]


Checking the network...

  Performing checks on the network ports
    Checking for backdoor ports                              [ None found ]
    Checking for hidden ports                                [ Skipped ]

  Performing checks on the network interfaces
    Checking for promiscuous interfaces                      [ None found ]

Checking the local host...

  Performing system boot checks
    Checking for local host name                             [ Found ]
    Checking for system startup files                        [ Found ]
    Checking system startup files for malware                [ None found ]

  Performing group and account checks
    Checking for passwd file                                 [ Found ]
    Checking for root equivalent (UID 0) accounts            [ None found ]
    Checking for passwordless accounts                       [ None found ]
    Checking for passwd file changes                         [ None found ]
    Checking for group file changes                          [ None found ]
    Checking root account shell history files                [ None found ]

  Performing system configuration file checks
    Checking for SSH configuration file                      [ Found ]
    Checking if SSH root access is allowed                   [ Not allowed ]
    Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed                   [ Not allowed ]
    Checking for running syslog daemon                       [ Found ]
    Checking for syslog configuration file                   [ Found ]
    Checking if syslog remote logging is allowed             [ Not allowed ]

  Performing filesystem checks
    Checking /dev for suspicious file types                  [ Warning ]
    Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]

[Press <ENTER> to continue]



System checks summary
=====================

File properties checks...
    Files checked: 137
    Suspect files: 1

Rootkit checks...
    Rootkits checked : 307
    Possible rootkits: 0

Applications checks...
    All checks skipped

The system checks took: 1 minute and 23 seconds

All results have been written to the log file (/var/log/rkhunter.log)

One or more warnings have been found while checking the system.
Please check the log file (/var/log/rkhunter.log)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is normal; `dhclient` uses raw packets and that's what triggers that warning.